# How to backup fresh OEM install of Windows 7 for a restoration

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore

I purchased a laptop with with Windows 7. The OEM did not provide the disc, but there is a Windows installation with a recovery partition. The Windows 7 machine has not been setup or activated.

I need to install a different operating system for testing. Installing the new operating system side-by-side will cause more trouble than its are worth, so I am going to install the new operating system over Windows 7. That is, I am going to "blow out" the existing Windows 7 installation.

Later, I may want to be able to revert to Windows 7. My question is, *how do I backup the current Windows 7 installation, without setup or activation, so I can use it again in the future, if desired*?

---

Many existing questions and answers, like [Ways of backup and restore/recovery in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/242157), [Making a backup of the system image in windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/770658) and [How to back up HP recovery partition](https://superuser.com/q/275030), presume the machine is setup. (I don't have an HP but I expect the process is similar).

I am trying to avoid the setup process because I want the "cleanest" untainted image as possible.

---

And so I am clear on what I am asking: I am looking for specific instructions, and not vague advice. For example, call out a tool you have used, and provide the two or three steps needed.

Sorry about this item. Without it, its seems like (1) the question could be vague or broad; and (2) I might create a useless backup image that does not restore (and I won't find out until sometime in the future). And testing a broken backup image will blow out things without a way to restore.

Comment: There will be a specific application software provided by the manufacturer of the laptop.In that application there must be a option  to create factory restore disks,in my opinion that's the best method.

Comment: What is the make and model of your PC?

Comment: @Rahul - I checked the box. There are no CDs or other media in it.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Its a Lenovo ThinkPad. All of Lenov's instructions I found depend upon the setup and activation being done. Hence the reason I stressed they were not done, and I need additional methods.

Comment: @jww Please see  my answer.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The activation is done by a marker in the BIOS ([SLIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_licensing_description_table#Identification)), a Digital OEM Certificate (`*.xrm-ms`) and a generic OEM product key.

On your currently installed OEM Windows search for the `OEM.xrm-ms`, make a backup of it and run a tool that can extract the currently used OEM key. Now save this Key + OEM.xrm-ms to an external drive and do a clean Windows 7 install.

After the setup, copy the OEM certificate to `C:\Windows\System32\OEM`, run `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\SLMGR.VBS -ilc %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OEM.xrm-ms`, next enter the OEM key with this command: `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\SLMGR.VBS -ipk KEY`.

After you done both, run this command to activate Windows:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\SLMGR.VBS -ato
```

Now you have a clean Windows which is activated via OEM key. Make a system image of it or create a [setupcomplete.cmd](http://blog.unidesk.com/tech/using-setupcompletecmd-windows-7-post-build-unattended-configurations-and-actions) which does all the steps on your own and added it to the Windows DVD so that the setup does all the steps on its own.

Comment: Thanks MagicAndre. Its looks like a good answer, but its not clear to me how to perform the backup. It seems like its prescribing how to setup the machine. I don't want to setup Windows or activate Windows.

Comment: why backup? do this to get a fresh and clean OEM install over and over again.

Comment: Where will the source image be located? As soon as I partition the disk and install the BSDs, Debian, Fedora, and Ubuntu, the OEM recovery partition will be lost.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to backup your current OEM windows? if yes, follow do this to save the OEM image to an USB drive: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/back-up-programs-system-settings-files#1TC=windows-7

Comment: There's a misunderstanding. The Windows machine has not been setup. It has never booted into Windows. The machine does not have a name, there are no accounts, the time has not been set, the license agreement has not been accepted, etc. The OEM has it ready to be setup, and they installed a recovery partition rather than providing a Windows CD (or is it a DVD now?).

Comment: For what its worth, I believe I only need to backup the Recovery Partition (and later restore it). But its only speculation on my part, and I am hoping someone who has done it can (1) confirm its required, and (2) provides the steps to ensure I have something that actually works.

Comment: ok, now I understand your issue. I never tried this so I can't answer this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The "cleanest" way to do this in my eyes would be to make a disk image of the entire disk as it stands. Then you can restore it to EXACTLY as it is today at any point in the future.

Something like a bootable copy of Acronis True Image will do this, or linux's dd can do so too I believe.

Comment: Also Macrium Reflect Free.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid this type of general advice, and trying to get something specific. Sorry I was not clear.

Comment: @jww how is Acronis not specific? Install their bootable media, create your backup image on an ext. HDD. I'm just not sure if it will let you select specific partitions to backup or clone the whole HDD.

Answer (score 0):

> I purchased a laptop with with Windows 7. [...] **there is a [..] recovery partition.**
>
> Later, I may want to be able to revert to Windows 7. My question is,
> how do I backup the current Windows 7 installation, without setup or
> activation, so I can use it again in the future, if desired?

The OEM recovery partition will restore the Windows installation, it *is* the 'fresh' backup. I.e. if you delete the 1 or 2 partitions belonging to Windows 7, then reboot into the OEM recovery mode, you can restore those deleted partitions. They will be in an uninitialized (i.e. not setup) state.

The problem is you didn't say if you were going to *also* delete the OEM recovery partition. If so, you will indeed need to back this up--or backup the windows partitions directly.

Since the act of restoring via the recovery partition resets your Windows, you are free to setup Windows first and use its native backup utility. Be sure to include the recovery partition, it will also copy the (now non-fresh) Windows partitions but you're not gonna use them. Then, whenever you want to 'reset' you should:

1. Restore the HDD from the above made image using a Windows 7 repair/installer DVD/USB/etc.
2. Boot into recovery and restore again to get the factory Windows settings (i.e. unitialized)

If restoring twice is too much work you can also backup the HDD without setting up Windows by using a bootable backup solution. Common brands are Norton Ghost, Acronis, Paragon. There are also free software options. For example you can make a bootable USB with the free Lazesoft recovery suite:

[image]

This will let you save the uninitialized Windows partitions(s) to another HDD. To 'reset' just boot from the backup media again and select restore. In this case you don't even need to backup the OEM recovery partition.

Answer (score -1):

There's a default application software provided by the manufactures on the PC's with pre-installed Windows like for Acer there is Acer Recovery Management,for Dell there is Dell Backup and Recovery Manager and for Lenovo I think there is Lenovo ThinkVantage Tools or OneKey Recovery.These tools are used to create factory restore disks for future use,previously I think they used to provide recovery media with the PC's but now they expect you to create one using the above mentioned respective tools.I am posting some links see if it helps:
https://support.lenovo.com/in/hi/documents/ht004960
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Welcome-FAQs-Knowledge-Base/How-to-create-quot-Factory-Default-Recovery-Disc-quot-with/ta-p/274167

Otherwise look for a similar tool in your laptop there must be one if the Windows came pre-installed.