# OEM License on Toshiba Qosmio X770

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, license

I wanna replace my HDD but before doing that I wanna know where exactly is my Windows 7 Home Premium OEM license located. Into the BIOS or HDD recovery partition, where and how can I know?

I found very interesting articles about how to replace a HDD and a tool that can retrieve your Windows SERIAL KEY number which I don't need because I have the sticker at the bottom of my laptop.

The thing is when I replace the HDD, I don't want to have problems with the license registration. I guess when I change the HDD, Win7 will require me to change the serial number by phone. But I wanna be sure of that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted here the steps: http://superuser.com/a/1000975/174557

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure Your Windows 7 license is located in BIOS SLIC table. So You can change HDD, install OS, enter SLIC serial for Your PC manufacturer and it will activate automatically. SLIC serial is "one for all", so You can found them in Internet, or it may be written in the COA certificate for Your PC.

Comment: Windows 7 license keys are not stored in firmware.  Only Windows 8 devices have the Windows license key stored in firmware.  ALL Windows 7 devices are required by Microsoft to have a COA label on the actual device.

Comment: license keys are not, I agree, but SLIC markers are in most cases. If You have such SLIC marker in Your PC, You enter serial number for this SLIC marker and get Windows 7 activated offline. ah, I forgot You have to run slmgr.vbs -ilc <...>\Toshiba.xrm-ms, which will install OEM certificate. such certificates may be easily found in Internet.